# rate of improvment in sampling

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes

I sequentially sample values from a distribution, say normal distribution. so I have:

```
x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_t, ...
```

as iid sequence.

However, I keep record of only the samples that are higher than the average samples I've kept on record.

```
y_1 = x_i1, y_2=x_i2, ..., y_n =y_in, ...
```

obviously i1 = 1 
and y_k >= mean(y_1,...,y_{k-1})

my questions are:

how does E(Y_n) behaves as a function of n? (obviously it is an increasing function, and E(Y_1)=E(X))

how does n behaves as a function of t? (as the recorded average increases we need to "wait" more time until we sample a good enough value, but how much more time do we need at each step)